# Casting type to object in C#

Tags: c#, casting

I have a function I want to make generic to display forms. I want the function to check if the form is opened already and if so bring it to the top if not create a new instance of the form and show it.

The first part of checking if the form is open is all good but I am having casting from T and creating a new form object of type T. I have used this line of code to create an instance of the form `obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();` but it does not show all the methods and properties in intellisense. Where as the code `Form x = new Form1.
x` will show all the methods and properties.

I am sure I am doing something wrong here any shine some light for me please.

```
     private static void ShowForm<T>(  )
    {
        T obj = default( T );

        List<T> opened = FormManager.GetListOfOpenForms<T>();
        if ( opened.Count == 0 )
        {
            // not opened

            // obj does not show all properties and methods
            obj = Activator.CreateInstance<T>();


            // x shows all properties and methods
            frmLogin x = new frmLogin();

        }
        else
        {
            // opened

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to constrain T to inherit `Form`:

```
private static void ShowForm<T>() where T : Form, new()
```

Once the compiler knows that `T` is guaranteed to inherit `Form`, you'll be able to use all members defined in `Form` or its base classes.

The more general answer to your question would be to cast `obj` to `Form`.

Comment: Is the constraint for a parameter-less constructor really that useful?

Comment: +1. @LightStriker, yes, it will allow to remove unnecessary reflection call to CreateInstance.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: Actually, `new T()` compiles to Activator.CreateInstance.  The constraint turns a runtime error into a compile-time error.